# Is there a built-in (or at least simple) way to check for the existence of a function accessible through $FPATH?

Tags: zsh

I want to define a function `foo` in a script (intended to be *sourced*), but only on the condition that some executable, shell built-in, function, or alias of that name doesn't already "exist".

The definition of "existence" in this case is not entirely trivial (hence the scare-quotes).

As a first approximation, my operational definition is that `foo` exists if `which foo` returns something other than `foo not found`.  This works for most cases I'm interested in...

```
% which cat
/bin/cat
% which cd
cd: shell built-in command
% which zargs
zargs () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XU
}
% which grep
grep: aliased to grep --color=always
```

...but it does not catch functions defined in files reachable through `$FPATH`:

```
% which zargs
zargs not found
```

Of course, I could roll my own wrapper around `which` to also check for functions under `$FPATH` (by explicitly iterating over it, etc.), but I've learned (or maybe over-learned) that, when it comes to shell programming, nothing is as simple as it looks...  Therefore, if there's already either 1) a built-in way to perform this existence test for available functions; or at least 2) an established idiom for doing this, I'd much prefer to go that route.

Comment: You mean test whether _any_ of the several thousand files in the various directories in your `$PATH` could provide a function if that file is sourced? Why would you want to do that? Surely it would be simpler to just check if the function is available and source the file if it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that is reachable through `fpath` does not “exist” in the sense that it can be invoked. It has to be autoloaded first, after which `which` (and any other method to test a function's existence) will report a stub definition that autoloads the real definition.

```
% zargs
zsh: command not found: zargs
% autoload zargs
% which zargs
zargs () {
        # undefined
        builtin autoload -X
}
```

`which foo` accurately test whether `foo` can be used as a command name, except for whatever `command_not_found_handler` might do. Since `command_not_found_handler` can contain arbitrary code, there's no way to predict what it'll do; and since it executes the substitute command if it finds one, there's no way to check what it would do without executing anything.

If your code is zsh-specific, you might use `whence` rather than `which` (or `whence -w` to get terser output, there's no option to make it silent), which is a wrapper around `whence`. If you want your code to be usable in other Bourne/POSIX-style shells, use `type`, not `which`.

```
function exists {
  whence -w $1 >/dev/null
}
```

If your definition of “exists” includes functions that might be autoloaded but aren't yet, then implement code that detects functions that might be autoloaded but aren't yet: traverse `$fpath` explicitly.